# Error when copying an array to another in Java

Tags: java, arrays, copy

After googling for a while, I'm aware that there quite a few ways to copy an array to another in Java, namely using System.arraycopy.

However a few of my friends tried to use this:

```
boolean a[][] = new boolean[90][90];
boolean b[][] = new boolean[90][90];

/* after some computations */

a = b
```

This produces a rather non deterministic result, does anyone know what this actually does?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not non-deterministic at all.

```
a = b;
```

simply assigns the value of `b` to `a`. The value of `b` is a reference to the array - so now both variables contain references to the same array. The old value of `a` is irrelevant - and if it referred to an array which nothing else referred to, it will now be eligible for garbage collection.

Note that this isn't specific to arrays - it's the way *all* reference types work in Java.

Basically, you're not copying one array into another at all - you're copying the *reference* to an array into another variable. That's all.

Comment: shouldn't that be "the old value of `a` is irrelevant"?

Comment: @thegravytalker: Absolutely. Oops. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Remember a=b means you are assigning value of b to a

```
    boolean a[][] = new boolean[90][90];
    boolean b[][] = new boolean[90][90];
    a[0][3]=false;
    b=a;
    a[0][5]=true;

    System.out.println(b[0][3]);
    System.out.println(b[0][5]);
```

The output is:-

false

true

Answer (score 0):

Lines of Code and their meanings:

```
boolean a[][] = new boolean[90][90];
```

Allocate an array and assign its reference to **a**

```
boolean b[][] = new boolean[90][90];
```

Allocate a second array and assign its reference to **b**

```
a = b;
```

Assign bs value (second arrays reference) to a.

### Before a=b;

```
a ---------> First arrays memory space

b ---------> Second arrays memory space
```

### After a=b;

```
a ---           First arrays memory space
     ---
        ------>
b ------------> Second arrays memory space
```

Now you lost first array forever